# How to filter based on the previous filtering

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

a table can be filtered either by Id, Buyer or Price. And the algorithm should be like this:

1.Filter Id, then filter Buyer based on the previous filter result, so does Price.
2. Filter Buyer, then filter Price based on the previous filter result, so does Id.
3. Filter Price, then filter Id based on the previous filter result, so does Buyer.

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtboxId_)
{
    items = dbContext.Items.Where(m => m.Id.Contains(_txtboxId_).ToList(); 
}
else
    items = dbContext.Items.ToList();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtboxBuyer_)
{
    items = dbContext.Items.Where(m => m.Id.Contains(_txtboxBuyer_).ToList();

}
else
    items = dbContext.Items.ToList();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtboxPrice_)
{
    items = dbContext.Items.Where(m => m.Id.Contains(_txtboxPrice_).ToList();

}
else
    items = dbContext.Items.ToList();
```

How am I suppose to do the filtering based on another result and doesn't matter which condition(Id, Buyer or Price) comes first?

Comment: Why do you have brackets for the `if` blocks but not for the `else`? you really should keep to one convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do `ToList()` till' you're done with your filters. Then, once all your filters are set correctly, make your query hit the database by calling  `ToList()` only once.

```
IQueriable<Items> items;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtboxId_)
{
    items = dbContext.Items.Where(m => m.Id.Contains(_txtboxId_); 
}
else
    items = dbContext.Items.ToList();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtboxBuyer_)
{
    items = dbContext.Items.Where(m => m.Id.Contains(_txtboxBuyer_);

}
else
    items = dbContext.Items.ToList();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtboxPrice_)
{
    items = dbContext.Items.Where(m => m.Id.Contains(_txtboxPrice_);

}

items = dbContext.Items.ToList();
```

Comment: The reason for this being that the query isn't generated and run against the database until it is enumerated, which is what `ToList()` does. The first time `ToList()` is called will pull the dataset and you will be filtering that as a list of objects rather than an SQL query.

Comment: @Heki By doing so you're bringing a lot of useless records to memory, degrading the performance of your application.

Comment: Ok after editing, there comes another problem. Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collection.Generic.List to System.LinQ.Iqueryable. Do I need a cast? @Oscar

Comment: @NgZen I have updated the code of my answer. Basically, changed the final assignment for a return clause

Answer (score 3):

You should use IQueryable and construct you entire query, then send it to the database only at the end by doing ToList().
Also you keep using the dbContext on each filter, use the same items variable if you want to keep the previous filters, this way you don't even need the second and third else branches

```
IQueryable<Item> items;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtboxId_)
{
    items = dbContext.Items.Where(m => m.Id.Contains(_txtboxId_); 
}
else
{
    items = dbContext.Items;
}

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtboxBuyer_)
{
    items = items.Where(m => m.Id.Contains(_txtboxBuyer_);
}

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtboxPrice_)
{
    items = items.Where(m => m.Id.Contains(_txtboxPrice_);
}

return items.ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest you not to call the ToList() method until you are done creating the collection of data you want to show or use.

I am not entirely sure this will sort your collection like you expect but try to look into the OrderBy Linq extension method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx